# Is it possible that $\|(z-a)^{-1}\|\gneq r((z-a)^{-1})$ for some $z\notin \sigma(a)$ but $\|(z-a)^{-2}\|= r((z-a)^{-2})\ \forall z\notin \sigma(a)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $a\in A$. In general, $\|(z-a)^{-1}\|\geq \|(z-a)^{-2}\|^{\frac{1}{2}}\ \forall z\notin \sigma(a)$. 
    Is it possible that   
  
                   $\|(z-a)^{-1}\|\gneq r((z-a)^{-1})$ for some $z\notin \sigma(a)$ but 
 $\|(z-a)^{-2}\|= r((z-a)^{-2})\ \forall z\notin \sigma(a)$? 
                      Is there a concrete example of this? For instance, for any non-normal matrix with the induced Euclidean norm, 
 $\|(z-a)^{-1}\|\gneq r((z-a)^{-1})$ for some $z\notin \sigma(a)$. Is it possible to have a non-normal matrix for which 
  
 $\|(z-a)^{-2}\|= r((z-a)^{-2})\ \forall z\notin \sigma(a)$?   
 I'd be grateful for a hint on how to begin. 
 Here, $r(b)$ denotes the spectral radius of an element $b\in A$.

Comment: Does $r(...)$ denote the spectral radius? My hunch for an example with the properties you're asking for would be an invertible, non-selfadjoint linear operator (on some Hilbert space) whose square is self-adjoint

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and 
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\sigma(a)=\{0,2\}$. Take $z=1$. Then
$$
z-a=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ (z-a)^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus
$$
(z-a)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ (z-a)^{-2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\|(z-a)^{-1}\|=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}2},\ \ \ r((z-a)^{-1})=1,
$$

$$
\|(a-z)^{-2}\|=1,\ \ \ r((z-a)^{-2})=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you. However, what I want is an example where $\|(z-a)^{-2}\|=r((z-a)^{-2})$ for every $z$ outside of the spectrum of $a$.